# Open VSCode with a blank slate

Tags: visual-studio-code

Sometimes I work on remote tasks, sometimes through a VPN which is not always active. When I restart VSCode, it will attempt to reload the workspace which takes me through a sequence of failures and delay.

Is there a way to configure VSCode so that is does not reload previously opened workspaces or files on startup? I would basically like to start VSCode with nothing loaded at all, and from that point I can load whichever project I desire.

Comment: You can try the command line option -n or --new-window. It Opens a new session of VS Code instead of restoring the previous session (default). [code -n]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `"window.restoreWindows": "none"` *controls how windows are being reopened after a restart*
- `"files.hotExit": "off"` controls whether unsaved files are remembered between sessions, allowing the save prompt when exiting the editor to be skipped.

You can open VSCode Settings by `Ctrl` + `,`, then search for the related keywords or directly manipulate the settings file like the above.